# React return function code block for dispatching actions always skip and return nothing

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

I'm following a tutorial of React-Redux, create a table showing the data, a modal Edit window is prompted when a record is clicked , after editing in modal window, click submit to call api for data update. but the submit callback function doesn't work.

myTable.js :  below button for invoke modal window for editing

```
<button className="btn-ghost-dark" onClick={(e) =>this.props.loadModalData(rowInfo.row._id, editable=false, e)}>
                                    <i className="fa fa-search fa-md"></i></button>
```

modalActions.js

```
export function loadModalData(oid, editable,e) {
e.preventDefault();
return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(beginAjaxCall());
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/inv/${oid}`)
        .then(rec => rec.json())
        .then(mdata=> {
            dispatch(mydetailsModal(mdata, editable));
        }).catch(error => {
        throw(error);
    });
};}
export function saveModalData(fulldata) { \\ actually call api to save data
console.log("this is called");
debugger; \\ the program run to here
return function (dispatch)  {
    debugger;  \\  seems never to be here, dont know why?
    console.log("never called");
};
```

}

detailsModal.js

```
import {saveModalData} from "../actions/modalActions";
class detailsModal extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(mdata, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...populate some formData..;

    saveModalData(formData);
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <ReactModal>
                  <form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" 
                        onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(this.props.mdata, e)}>
                  .....
                  <button type="submit" hidden={!this.props.editable} > Submit </button>
                </ReactModal>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

the question is in function saveModalData, the Return Function part seems never to be executed, is there somthing wrong with my code, i compared to the loadModalData function, cant find the root cause, newbie to ES/React/Javascript :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you're calling `saveModalData(formData);`. In your case you want to invoke the function in the return so you'd have to do `saveModalData(formData)();` This is called [`currying`](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/). See how the example bellow behaves.

```js
function outside(){
    console.log('hello from outside');
    return function(){
        console.log('hello from inside')
    }
}

outside(); // without currying
console.log('-----')
outside()() // with currying
```